# Is it normal to have 2 IPv4 DNS addresses on my PC?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ipv4

I'm new here and not very knowledgeable when it comes to computers so I'm sorry if my question comes across stupid. I have been working from home and I checked my WiFi connection on properties (using Windows 10). I noticed I have DHCP and my standard IP address, but it also shows 2 IPv4 DNS server addresses. I am just wondering is this normal/standard? I have never changed or amended my router settings. The only thing I can think this may be (but I could be horribly wrong), is that my router has both 2g and 5g connections. I am worried incase potentially my router has been compromised. Any help would be so appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

DNS addressing commonly needs an alternate in case one server is momentarily (or longer) not available.

All the DNS settings I see (workstations, routers, servers) allow for 2 (sometimes more) DNS Servers.

So what you see is entirely normal and (by itself) does not put you at any higher risk.

Comment: John, thank you so much. You've really helped put my mind at ease. Have the best day

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible interpretations for the question:

- two DNS addresses (suggested by the question text).
- two IPv4 addresses (suggested by title).

2 DNS addresses is normal; the system will just use the second one if the first one is unavailable (or alternate between the two, not sure).

2 IPv4 addresses are normal too. You may be connected to two different networks at the same time (most commontly -- wired and wireless, or your home + VPN connection). Each "internet" connection provides a distinct IP.

Given what you have mentioned here, this alone is nothing to worry about.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, I meant 2IPv4, thank you for explaining both though. Yeah I am connected to home and VPN so that would make sense! Would it be normal that my main IP is 192 but both IPv4 begin with 194? Thank you for your help again.